# ASP.Net C# Webforms 40 second plus run time pulling from database. What is wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a website that was built in ASP.Net/Visual Studio.  A page in it pulls blog text from a MS SQL database.  The text in each post is a couple thousand characters, and there are only 14 rows in the database, and when I pull up the site, it takes up to 40 seconds to load.  It isn't my internet connection or PC.  It is hosted on GoDaddy windows hosting (shared), and they told me their servers were working fine, and it had to be a problem with my code.  I have used basically the exact same code on another site with a different host with no such delays.  For that matter, this same site ran much faster on another host before we moved it.

The page causing the problem is http://www.triggerfind.com/blog/blog.aspx

I used a trace to find out exactly which line is causing the problem.  The code that is running on Page_Load is:

```
Trigger4.AppCode.PostModel model = new Trigger4.AppCode.PostModel();
List<Post> blogPosts = new List<Post>();
blogPosts = model.GetAllPosts();
DisplayPosts(blogPosts, 1, 1);
```

The one line that is causing all the delay is:

```
blogPosts = model.GetAllPosts();
```

which calls the following function in a separate file:

```
public List<Post> GetAllPosts()
    {
        try
        {
            using (triggerDBEntities db = new triggerDBEntities())
            {
                List<Post> ps = (from x in db.Posts
                                 orderby x.DateTime descending
                                 select x).ToList();
                return ps;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Also, when I access the DB using SQL Server Management Studio, and select the first 1000 rows, it comes up in less than a second.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this awful load time?

Am I doing something wrong or is it the host's fault?

Comment: Every request or first one only?

Comment: In code you are selecting all data from database ? How many records are there in this table ?

Comment: the .GetAllPosts()  return how many records?

Comment: GetAllPosts returns 14 records from the table.  Each row has one blog entry (500-1000 words approx.) and a couple other small columns (eg. DateTime, Tags).  So it isn't returning a huge amount of data, or I would have used a more selective query.

Comment: It seems to happen on the first one only.  After getting to blog.aspx, if you select another entry (there is a sidebar which links to other posts using ".aspx?id=xx"), it loads very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> For that matter, this same site ran much faster on another host before
>   we moved it.

You answered it yourself

Comment: Our last host had terrible downtime issues.  It would be down for days at a time for no reason, and their support could never tell me why.  That is why we moved it.

Comment: Have you used network analyzer to see what's wrong? Ctrl+Shift+Q on Firefox, and for Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I >Network
Sorting also gives a big charge to SQL server, but you said that you have a very few record right now.

Another thing I was thinking also,
When you use the keyword `using`, the object will be released when getting out from it. But you have return there and the object wont't be released. Try to have the variable outside of the `using` then return the value at the last only